GOMAXPROCS not setting the number of processors as expected
I am just doing some testing to see if I can run Go while calling Fortran functions for some scientific purposes. I want to compare the capabilities of goroutines run on one core verses all 22 cores of my computer. When I run the following code, I can see 20 of my 22 processors being used regardless of what GOMAXPROCS is set to. When I set it to 1, I should only have 1 processors running, right? Thus it would be much slower. Then setting it to 22 or NumCPU() would be faster. Additionally, if someone could help me understand why only 20 processors are being used when I have 22, that would be nice.
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: mylib.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8 -lgfortran
// double calc( double );
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func simulate(numberOfSteps int, returnValues chan C.double, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    iValue := C.double(0.0)
    for i := 0; i < numberOfSteps; i++ {
        iValue = C.double(i)
        returnValues <- C.calc(iValue)
    }
}

func test_cpu_count(numberOfProcessors int, numberOfSimulations int, numberOfSteps int) {
    fmt.Println("\nNumber of cores:", numberOfProcessors)
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numberOfProcessors) // set number of cores to 1 (not default for Go)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup // For synchronizing goroutines
    wg.Add(numberOfSimulations)

    returnValues := make(chan C.double, numberOfSimulations*numberOfSteps)
    concurrentStart := time.Now()
    for index := 0; index < numberOfSimulations; index++ {
        go simulate(numberOfSteps, returnValues, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Runtime:", time.Now().Sub(concurrentStart))
}

func main() {
    const numberOfSimulations int = 22
    const numberOfSteps int = 800

    //*****************************************************
    // Concurrency and Parallelism
    // First Concurrent on a single core
    //*****************************************************
    numThreads := 1
    test_cpu_count(numThreads, numberOfSimulations, numberOfSteps)

    //***********************************************************
    // Now Parallel on all cores
    //***********************************************************
    numThreads = runtime.NumCPU()
    test_cpu_count(numThreads, numberOfSimulations, numberOfSteps)

}


I cannot be certain why 20 vs 22 "processors", though a question I have there is do you mean cores or virtual CPU's?  i.e. are we talking 11 hyper-threading cores or 22 physical cores?
In any event, I suspect that the number of steps is sufficiently low that you aren't saturating the "processors".  i.e. by the time your program is starting goroutines #21 and #22, goroutines #1 and #2 (or more) may have already finished so the goroutine scheduler doesn't need to use the "remaining" processors.
Or it could be that the 2 unused cores are efficiency cores that the scheduler is avoiding.

As to why GOMAXPROCS(1) does not seem to be having any effect, although it may be called at any point, the value applied will only take effect at the next "Stop the World" GC intervention.  If your code never encounters a "Stop the World" moment, your GOMAXPROCS() will never have any effect.  This may be what is happening here.

Look all this is complicated like in "fucking complicated". There are physical cores, virtual (hyper-threading) cores on these physical cores, OS threads running on virtual cores, goroutines running on these OS threads. Scheduling of OS threds to cores and scheduling of goroutines to OS thread has to be done. This is all really complicated and a simplified model like "GOMAXPROCS is the maximum number of processes and that should be able to reach the 'number of cores' I have" just doesn't describe the real sutuation.

Now if you base your experiments on a flawed (because too simple) model of the word your experiment won't show you what is going on in the real world but just show you where (and possibly why) your simplified model is lacking.

You are making calls via cgo which are going to require their own threads regardless of GOMAXPROCS. The scheduling and cgo overhead probably dwarfs the work being done by double anyway, so you are not benchmarking what you intended at all.

From the documentation:

The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously. There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit. This package's GOMAXPROCS function queries and changes the limit.

So, everything works according to documentation: You'll run a maximum of one thread with user-level Go code which then hands over to your custom C (Fortran) code, which is not controlled by the Go scheduler. It is then free to run other go code on this thread.
Whether your Fortran function is blocked on I/O or does calculations on a CPU core is no concern to the Go runtime, the Go scheduler sees that this thread is not available for Go code and uses another one.
